# Easy way to swap Relics/Implants?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Is there an easy way to swap the 2nd implant or relic?

Everytime I try to swap it I have to open character screen drag the item to the correct itemslot and It's pretty annoying tbh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a long-standing complaint and sadly there is no way to swap both relics/implants without opening your character sheet.

To avoid dragging you can right-click one or both of your equipped relics to remove it/them, and then you can right-click both of the relics you want to equip.  That means the de-equipped relic(s) will be in the first open slot(s) your inventory had rather than where the other relics were, however, which can also be annoying.